# Password validation

Tags: validation, passwords

I need to validate a password with the following requirements:
1. Be at least seven characters long
2. Contain at least one letter (a-z or A-Z)
3  Contain at least one number (0-9)
4  Contain at least one symbol (@, $, %, etc) 
Can anyone give me the correct expression?

Comment: Doing it with regular expression may not be a right idea, But you can write some individual regular expression to check each condition

Comment: Do you mean to use regular expressions? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Btw, requiring passwords to contain symbols is a bad idea. It doesn't increase the number of available options much, but it causes trouble easily with foreign keyboard layouts and such. Requiring lower and upper case and a numbers already gives an alphabet of 62, which is enough, as long as the password is long enough (at least 8 characters these days).

Answer (score 3):

1. `/.{7,}/`
2. `/[a-zA-Z]/`
3. `/[0-9]/`
4. `/[-!@#$%^`...`]/`

Answer (score 1):

For a single regex, the most straightforward way to check all of the requirements would be with [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]).{7,}/
```

Breaking it down:

1. `.{7,}` - at least seven characters
2. `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` - a letter must occur somewhere after the start of the string
3. `(?=.*\d)` - ditto 2, except a digit
4. `(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9\s])` - ditto 2, except something not a letter, digit, or whitespace

However, you might choose to simply utilize multiple separate regex matches to keep things even more readable - chances are you aren't validating a ton of passwords at once, so performance isn't really a huge requirement.